# SQL: Filter rows where event of type A happened without event of type B happening within 1 second of event of type A

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

let's assume I have a Table that looks like this:

```
timestamp                    event       
2021-06-01 12:00:00.000      A          
2021-06-01 12:00:00.200      B          
2021-06-01 12:00:00.500      C          
2021-06-01 12:00:01.700      A
2021-06-01 12:00:02.000      D
2021-06-01 12:00:03.000      B
```

I want to select timestamps of all events A where event B and C has not happened within 1 second of event A.

So from the example above, timestamp 2021-06-01 12:00:01.700 would be returned.

Preferably in SQL Server, but any SQL syntax will do to help me figure out how to write such query.

Comment: Please share your best attempt

Answer (score 4):

We can use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT timestamp, event
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE event = 'A' AND
      NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM yourTable t2
          WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(ms, t2.timestamp, t1.timestamp)) <= 1000 AND
                t2.event IN ('B', 'C')
      );
```

### Demo

Read in plain English, the above query says to return any record which is an `A` event, for which we cannot find a `B` or `C` event record which is within 1 second or less (either before or after) of the `A` record.

Comment: another version :)
 SELECT timestamp, event
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE event = 'A' AND
     1 > (
          SELECT count(*)
          FROM yourTable t2
          WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(ms, t2.timestamp, t1.timestamp)) <= 1000 AND
                t2.event IN ('B', 'C')
      );